# Can I compile a dynamic lib on Linux and link on Windows?

Tags: c++, c, dll, cross-compiling, .so

I run Linux (specifically Ubuntu 20.04), and would like to know if there is a way to produce a dynamic library that could be linked against on a Windows machine. I am using GNU `make` and a `mingw` cross-compiler to attempt to do this.

Here is the simple makefile I have made for testing purposes:

```
CXX := x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++
CXX_FLAGS := -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++

main.exe: example.dll test_exe.o
    $(CXX) $(CXX_FLAGS) -o main.exe test_exe.o -L. -lexample

example.dll: example.o
    $(CXX) $(CXX_FLAGS) -shared -o example.dll example.o -Wl,--out-implib,libexample.a

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) -c -fPIC $<
```

For reference: I have a file `example.hpp` which declares the methods that I want to be included in the library, and these methods are defined in `example.cpp`. `test_exe.cpp` contains my `main` function, and calls methods defined in the library. Running `make` generates (I believe) object files `example.o` and `test_exe.o`, followed by a dynamically linked library named `example.dll` and its corresponding import library named `libexample.a`, and then links everything together into an executable called `main.exe`. The produced output appears to be doing this, but I have no way of completely verifying if the output files are actually what I expect them to be.

Additionally, I have `CXX_FLAGS` set to statically link the `c` and `c++` standard libraries because when I do not, I get an error saying `The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)`. I am guessing this is because by default the files expect a Linux version of the standard libraries (which would not be found on a Windows machine), and explicitly linking overrides this option? Google says this error may indicate that I have the wrong application version for my machine, so it makes sense.

The echoed commands from when I run `make` are:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -c -fPIC example.cpp
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -shared -o example.dll example.o -Wl,--out-implib,libexample.a
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -c -fPIC test_exe.cpp
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -o main.exe test_exe.o -L. -lexample
```

When I link in Linux, everything works mostly as expected. The executable runs on Windows as long as the `.dll` is in the current directory, and produces an error when it is removed.

The first thing I did not expect is that the executable will run whether or not the import library `libmath.a` is present. I was under the assumption that I was linking against the import library which indirectly wraps the dynamic library, but this does not appear to be the case. Does anyone know what is actually happening, and why I am not linking against the import library?

My other question takes a bit more explanation. Ideally, I would like to be able to create a dynamic library on Linux, send it to a Windows machine, and link it into an arbitrary executable there. I am not entirely sure if this is possible, because Windows has to specify `__declspec(dllexport)` while Linux does not, but would like to know if it is. I have tried moving my dynamic and import libraries (`example.dll` and `libexample.a`), along with my library header file (`example.hpp`) into a directory with a new file (`testapp.cpp`) specifying an alternate `main` method.

On a Windows machine, I run `g++ -c testapp.cpp` to produce an object file, and then try to link. When I run `g++ -o app.exe testapp.o -L. -lexample` to try to generate an executable linked to the dynamic library (through the import library) I get the following error: `undefined reference to 'square(int)'`. `square(int)` is a function that is defined in the library, returning the square of an integer. I have also tried marking the function in my header file as `__declspec(dllimport)`, which changes the error message to: `undefined reference to '_imp___Z6squarei'`. Is it possible on Windows to link against a .dll that did not originally specify `__declspec(dllexport)` for its functions (i.e. one developed in Linux)?

Build OS: Ubuntu 20.04 - version 9.3.0 of g++

Target OS: Windows 10 (tested in a virtualbox vm) - version 9.2.0 of g++

Comment: Try linking specifically with the import library, i,e, specify `libexample.a` rather than `-lexample`.

Comment: Same error. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: This is strange, can you run `nm -C libexample.a` and `nm -CD example.dll`?

Comment: I get different results depending on which OS I run those commands in. On windows, the first prints out a series of lines like `nm: d0000xx.o: file format not recognized`, and the second says `nm: example.dll: file format not recognized`. On linux, the prints out a series of the same `nm: d0000xx.o`, but is followed by what I assume is information describing each identifier. Strangely, the second tells me `nm: example.dll: no symbols`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually got it. The command that worked was: `g++ -o alt.exe testapp.o libexample.a`. I am not entirely sure why this works when what I tried before did not, but it does work as expected now.

Interestingly, it still works even if I do not specify `__declspec(dllimport)` anywhere. I am also not sure why this works, but my best guess is that I am still using a GNU compiler, and not a windows default one.